Requests after logging in stay pending
I recently deployed my first full stack app on render:
I can successfully register and log in, but any requests made while being logged in get stuck pending and won't resolve.
I assume it has something to do with cookies not being able to travel between front- and backend, but they are set correctly when checking chrome dev tools.
FRONTEND: https://example.com
NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND: https://api.example.com
cookiesOptions:
const cookiesOptions: CookieOptions = {
  sameSite: "none",
  secure: true,
  domain: ".example.com",
  httpOnly: true,
};

CORS:
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: process.env.FRONTEND,
    credentials: true,
  })
);

loginUserHandler (backend):
export const loginUserHandler = async (
  req: Request<{}, {}, LoginUserInput>,
  res: Response,
  next: NextFunction
) => {
  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    const user = await findUserByEmail({ email });

    // 1. Check if user exist
    if (!user) {
      return next(new AppError(401, "Invalid email or password"));
    }

    
    // 2. Check if password is valid
    if (!(await User.comparePasswords(password, user.password))) {
      return next(new AppError(401, "Invalid email or password"));
    }
  

    // 3. Sign Access and Refresh Tokens
    const { access_token, refresh_token } = await signTokens(user);

    // 4. Add Cookies
    res.cookie("access_token", access_token, accessTokenCookieOptions);
    res.cookie("refresh_token", refresh_token, refreshTokenCookieOptions);
    res.cookie("logged_in", true, {
      ...accessTokenCookieOptions,
      httpOnly: false,
    });

    // 5. Send response
    res.status(200).json({
      status: "success",
      access_token,
    });

  } catch (err: any) {
    next(err);
  }
};


login (frontend):
export async function login(email: string, password: string) {
  const response = await fetch(
    `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND}/api/auth/login`,
    {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-type": "application/json" },
      credentials: "include",
      body: JSON.stringify({
        email,
        password,
      }),
    }
  );
  return response;
}


Until here, everything works fine. I am able to log in and the cookies are set.
The following does not work after being logged in.
getMeHandler (backend):
export const getMeHandler = async (
  req: Request,
  res: Response,
  next: NextFunction
) => {
  try {
    const user = res.locals.user;

    if (!user) {
      return next(new AppError(404, "User not found"));
    }

    res.status(200).status(200).json({
      status: "success",
      data: {
        user,
      },
    });
  } catch (err: any) {
    next(err);
  }
};


getUser (frontend):
export async function getUser() {
  const response = await fetch(
    `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND}/api/users/me`,
    {
      method: "GET",
      credentials: "include",
    }
  );
  const responseData: IresponseData = await response.json();
  if (responseData.status === "error") {
    throw new UserError("Oh no, could not get the requested user information!");
  } else if (responseData.data) {
    return responseData.data.user;
  }
}


